# Split the text file on date based in pentaho

Tags: pentaho

I have one text file and I want to split this file into multiple output files on the basis of dates.

```
Dates       Keywords
201506-17   iphone 5
201506-16   iphone 4
201506-15   iphone 3
201506-14   iphone 2
201506-13   iphone 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked on your logic. I explain step by step please follow.

Step 1:- Create one transformation call `transformation_1`.

Data Grid=> result is like these

```
Dates       Keywords
201506-17   iphone 5
201506-16   iphone 4
201506-15   iphone 3
201506-14   iphone 2
201506-13   iphone 1
```

Modified Java Script Value => like below image

[image]

Finally `transformation_1` is like these.

[image]

Step 2: Create another transformation called `transformation_2`. Like below image

[image]

Step 3: Create another transformation called `transformation_3`. Like below image.

[image]

Step 4: Create job  called `sub_job_1`. Like below image.

[image]

Step 5: Create job  called `main_job_1`. Like below image.

[image]

===> important step after completed main_job_1. Check these option **Execute for every input row**. like below image.

[image]

Finally run main_job_1. It successfully created 5 files.

I think these information is useful to you.

Thank you.